# How to keep in mind the value of a checkbox of a custom post type Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have been trying for some days to keep checking my checkboxes after updating an article for example

Having already tried different thing either I have the boxes that are not checked or both check themselves while only one was checked basic, however, the registration in the database is good it's just a problem d display, Can you help me?

```
<div class="meta-box-item-content" style="padding-bottom:0.3rem; ">
  <input type="checkbox" id="<?= $id; ?>" name="<?= $id; ?>" value="Fastcat" <?php if(isset($_POST['<?= $id; ?>']) AND in_array(Fastcat, $_POST['<?= $id; ?>'])) {echo  'checked="checked"';} 
?>>
<label for="<?= $value; ?>">FASTCAT</label>
</div>
```

I wish that when I update that I update or that I send the form the checkbox remains checked or uncheck if people unchecked

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `checked()` function - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked instead of your current solution